# Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send

Tags: android, flutter, dart, pusher, foreground-service

I've used pusher_client inside background service via flutter_foreground_task package. Pusher client listen truly inside background service but some time later when message came it gives this error `W/FlutterJNI( 5311): Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: com.github.chinloyal/pusher_client_stream. Response ID: 0`
Could anybody help me please.